# Merge two dataframes when specific condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'IP':['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3','4.4.4.4','5.5.5.5'],
    'ID':['101','202','303','404','505'],
    'Name':['aqua','noctua','ytube','tech','logi'],
    'Price':[100,200,300,400,500]
    })

df1 = pd.DataFrame ({
    'IP':['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3','4.4.4.4','6.6.6.6'],
    'ID':['101','202','303','404','606'],
    'Name':['atlas','noctua','ytube','tech','smash'],
    'Price':[600,700,800,900,990]

    })
print(df)
        IP   ID    Name  Price
0  1.1.1.1  101    aqua    100
1  2.2.2.2  202  noctua    200
2  3.3.3.3  303   ytube    300
3  4.4.4.4  404    tech    400
4  5.5.5.5  505    logi    500

print(df1)
        IP   ID    Name  Price
0  1.1.1.1  101   atlas    600
1  2.2.2.2  202  noctua    700
2  3.3.3.3  303   ytube    800
3  4.4.4.4  404    tech    900
4  6.6.6.6  606   smash    990

new=df1.merge(df,indicator=True,how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
print(new)
        IP   ID    Name  Price     _merge
0  1.1.1.1  101   atlas    600  left_only
1  2.2.2.2  202  noctua    700  left_only
2  3.3.3.3  303   ytube    800  left_only
3  4.4.4.4  404    tech    900  left_only
4  6.6.6.6  606   smash    990  left_only
```

The new dataframe called **new** should contain only data from df1 when the combination of IP and ID is unique among the two dataframes(I don't care about the other columns). Hence the correct output is:

```
        IP   ID    Name  Price     _merge
0  6.6.6.6  606   smash    990  left_only
```

What do I need to change in my code to get this output? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the how parameter in pandas merge, it takes the columns based on which you want to merge:

```
new=df1.merge(df,indicator=True,how='left', on=['IP', 'ID']).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']

print(new)
 IP   ID Name_x  Price_x Name_y              Price_y     _merge
4  6.6.6.6  606  smash      990    NaN                  nan  left_only
```

If you don't pass it, pandas will try to infer based on the data frames which my cause some problems like this, so I always like to pass it to prevent bugs,

Answer (score 1):

You can merge IP and ID to a str and compare it with df.

```
new = df1.loc[~df1.IP.str.cat(df1.ID).isin(df.IP.str.cat(df1.ID))]
```